# PHP issue with submitting form and storing in the Database, small issue giving me strife

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to store information sent via a form into a MySQL DB. It doesn't load the next page nor does it store the information.

My header requires init.php which I can confirm has the correct database connection credentials.

The following is my HTML and "uploader" script - I know it must be something silly but this is where the issue lies, in the html and/or the uploader.php.

If someone could run through my code and point out each issue (and possibly a re-work of my code) it would be very much appreciated! Thank you!!

**HTML** *(I've reduced the Date of Birth options so there's less code here)*

```
        <h2>Choose Your File</h2>
                 <form id="submit-photo" action="index.php?p=uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />   
            <div id="FileUpload">

                <input type="file" name="photo" id="BrowserHidden" onchange="getElementById('FileField').value = getElementById('BrowserHidden').value;" />

                <div id="BrowserVisible"><input type="text" id="FileField" /></div>
            <span class="error"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['flash_message']['photo'])) echo $_SESSION['flash_message']['photo'] ?>
            </span></div>               

            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
            <label for="dob">DOB</label>
            <div class="dob-select">
            <select name="dob_day" id="dob_day">
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dob-select">
            <select name="dob_month" id="dob_month">
            <option value="01">Jan</option>
            <option value="02">Feb</option>
            <option value="03">Mar</option>
            <option value="04">Apr</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dob-select">
            <select name="dob_year" id="dob_year">
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                <input type="text" class="short" name="postcode" id="postcode">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>                
                <label for="subscribe"><input type="checkbox" class="left" id="subscribe"> <p class="left">subscribe</p></label>
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </fieldset>       
        </form>
```

**DB Columns**

- id *(auto-incremented)*
- name
- photo *(path to file)*
- email
- date *(date of birth: day, month, year to be combined to form this)*
- postcode
- subscribe *(should be 0 or 1)*
- approve
- created *(timestamp)*

[image: Database]

**Uploader PHP**

```
<?php $error = array();
require_once 'init.php';
//Is request?
if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post') {

    //$friend = ( $_POST['friend'] == 'true' ) ? 1 : 0;

    $required_array = array(
        'name' => 'Name',
        'dob_day' => 'Day',
        'dob_month' => 'Month',
        'dob_year' => 'Year',
        'postcode' => 'Postcode',
        'email' => 'Email Address',
        'subscribe' => 'subscribe'
    );
    $required_error = array();
    foreach( $required_array as $field_name => $field ) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$field_name]) OR empty($_POST[$field_name]) OR $_POST[$field_name] == '') {
            $required_error[$field_name] = 'Please insert your '. $field;
        }
    }

    $_POST['email'] = verify_email($_POST['email']);
    if($_POST['email'] == FALSE && !isset($error['email']))
        $error['email'] = 'Please use a valid email address';


    //Validate the form key
    if(!isset($_POST['form_key']) || !$formKey->validate()) {
        //Form key is invalid, show an error
        $error['general'] = 'Use the real form!';
    } else {
        if((!empty($_FILES["photo"])) && ($_FILES['photo']['error'] == 0)) {
            $filename = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
            $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

            //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 1Mb
            if ( ($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] <= 5242880) ) {
                //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
                $newname = str_replace( ' ', '_', trim( strip_tags( $_POST['name'] ) ) ) . _ . $formKey->generateKey() . '_' . time() . '.jpg';

                //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
                if (!file_exists($newname)) {
                    if (sizeof($required_error) == 0) {
                        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
                        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], './photos/'. $newname))) {
                            $move_status = 'done';
                        } else {
                            $error['photo'] = "A problem occurred during file upload!";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $error['photo'] = "File ".$_FILES["photo"]["name"]." already exists";
                }
            } else {
                $error['photo'] = "Only .jpg images under 5Mb are accepted for upload". $_FILES["photo"]["size"] . $_FILES["photo"]["type"] . '====' . $ext;
            }
        } else {
            $error['photo'] = "No photo uploaded";
        }
    }

    $error = $error + $required_error;

    if (sizeof($error) == 0 AND $move_status == 'done') {
                    $_POST['date'] = $_POST['dob_day'].'-'.$_POST['dob_month'].'-'.$_POST['dob_year'];
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `$db_name`.`submissionform` (`id` , `name` , `photo` , `email` , `date` , `postcode` , `subscribe` , `approve` , `created` )
            VALUES ( NULL , '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($newname),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subscribe']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['approve']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message'])
            );
        mysql_query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=0');
        $result1 = mysql_query($query);

        $last_id = mysql_insert_id();

        if ($result1)
            $success = 'Done';
        else
            $error['general'] = 'Error when submitting your form, please try again.';

        //mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close();
    }

}


if ($success == 'Done') {
    $page = 'uploader';
    include 'header.php';
    echo '<img height="782" style="float:left;" src="./assets/img/success.png" />';
    include 'footer.php';
} else {
    $_SESSION['flash_message'] = $error;
    $_SESSION['recent_field'] = $_POST;
    header('Location: ./index.php');
}
?>
```

**edit**: I did some debugging- by placing `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of uploader.php

Errors are:

Notice: Undefined variable: success in ..../uploader.php on line 100

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at..../uploader.php:100) in ....uploader.php on line 110

Comment: I've never seen require_once written like that, is it a typo or does it not need ()? I thought it should be `require_once('init.php');`

Comment: @Adam: It also works that way. Check the comments on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Yup can work either way.

Comment: Cool good to know, just never seen it before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkbox `subscribe` doesn't have a `name` field, in these lines,

```
<fieldset>                
   <label for="subscribe"><input type="checkbox" class="left" id="subscribe"> <p class="left">subscribe</p></label>
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</fieldset>
```

So the `check` inside `foreach` won't pass through.

```
foreach( $required_array as $field_name => $field ) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$field_name]) OR empty($_POST[$field_name]) OR $_POST[$field_name] == '') {
        $required_error[$field_name] = 'Please insert your '. $field;
    }
}
```

Also, `$_POST['form_key']` is not being set, which wouldn't pass this line,

```
//and subsequently have an $error and not execute the query.
if(!isset($_POST['form_key']) || !$formKey->validate()) {
```

Is `id` a primary key? you're inserting a `NULL` value to it, in the query. It won't auto-increment if you pass an `id` value in the query.

Comment: Nice pick up, thank you! Would that be preventing it from submitting? Anything else you can see wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. If you spot anythin else please let me know, I'm going to start implementing those and see how it goes..

Comment: No problem, I'm updating my answer, as I find more issues.

Comment: ID is primary..
Thanks @coder1984. Feel free to run a live test :) trying to debug this thing..

Comment: Then thats a major problem :)...just don't pass any value to that field, so the query would be `$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO $db_name.submissionform  VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );",`

Comment: Whoops, it's set to auto-increment.. http://i50.tinypic.com/tzbs0.png for a screenshot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18582/discussion-between-dave-and-coder1984)

Comment: I did some debugging- by placing `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of uploader.php

Errors are:

Notice: Undefined variable: success in ..../uploader.php on line 100

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at..../uploader.php:100) in ....uploader.php on line 110